# Can Saturn Ion 2 sedan passenger side manual mirror be replaced with coupe's manual remote mirror?

Tags: saturn, wing-mirrors

Can the manual remote passenger side mirror from a Saturn Ion 2 coupe fit on the sedan?

I need to replace the passenger side mirror on my Saturn Ion 2 sedan (that wasn't a bush, it was a tree!). There's a manual remote mirror for Ion coupes, like the driver side manual remote in the sedan, which would be a slight upgrade (easier adjustments, no need to open the window) from the plain manual mirror that's available for sedans. The sedan door has a hole which looks like the joystick housing would fit through, though the sail panel doesn't. Would the sail panel from a coupe fit the sedan door? Are there any other necessary alterations?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!